# bool как вектор , что больше одной цифры имеют значение true. А также проблема с вектором ,так как он не берет последнюю цифры

Tags: c++

Как можно узнать, если в буллеоне вектора больше 2 цифр имеют значение true?

```
for (routeIterator4 = routes[i].begin(); routeIterator4 != routes[i].end(); routeIterator4++)
{
    for (routeIterator7 = routes[j].begin(); routeIterator7 != routes[j].end(); routeIterator7++)
    {
        if (routeIterator4->x == routeIterator7->x)
        {
            visitedPoint[routeIterator7->x] = true;
        }
    }
}
if (visitedPoint[true] < 2)   
{               
    for (routeIterator3 = routes[i].end() - 1; routeIterator3 != routes[i].begin(); routeIterator3--)
    {
        taker.x = routeIterator3->x;
        routes[j].push_back(taker);
    }
}
```

Дальше хочу проверить, если больше 1 цифра имеет значение true, мне не нужно продолжать. Написал в таком виде, но не работает.

И второй вопрос, если я захожу в вектор с end, почему он не берет самую первую цифры, например у меня список цифр `1,2,3,4,5,6,10`, он возьмет и добавит все цифры, кроме единицы.. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то странно написано с точки зрения русского языка. Я не до конца понял вопрос, но попробую ответить, как понял

1) Если вы поняли, что продолжать цикл не надо, то воспользуйтесь командой `break;`

2) Метод `end()` возвращает итератор, указывающий на элемент, **следующий за последним**, а не на последний. То есть итератор на последний элемент - это `--end();`

Comment: Алексей , я это прекрасно понимаю и использую , метод break.. Вопрос идет в том , что я не могу проверить , сколько цифр имеют значение true ... Используя  if (visitedPoint[true] < 2)  , он не работает так , как необходимл.

Comment: Второй вопрос , я не понял ваш ответ.. Вы могли бы пожалуйста указать , как нужно создать цикл, чтобы он брал все цифры во внимание ?

Comment: @MishaOstapchuk Ааа, теперь понял. проверить - циклом пройтись по всему массиву, считая кол-во `true` (ну или пока 2 на найдете, потом break). В вашем случае во вложенном цикле в операторе `if` я бы прибавлял 1 к какой-нибудь переменной `count`, которая показывает кол-во `true`

Comment: @MishaOstapchuk по поводу второго. Если нужно пройти с конца, то цикл начинается с --end(), а потом проблема. Для `begin()` в общем случае операция декремента (`--`) не определена. Проще всего условие выхода из цикла сделать в конце его тела. То есть в конце цикла добавить что-то вроде `if(routeIterator3 == begin()) break;`

Comment: спасибо , это отличная идея и извиняюсь за вопрос , который приводит только к новым вопросам.. Второй вопрос , я решил использовать reverse , так как я не знаю почему он не берет во внимание первую цифру. Спасибо вам большое

Comment: Есть же обратные итераторы. Зачем городить какие-то велосипеды?

Comment: @alexolut да, я сразу как-то про них не вспомнил, написал такой костыль. Когда вспомнил - автор уже меня опередил сам.